# Обработка объекта внутри HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Есть такой [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahbv2cn/):

Набор данных:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Item 1',
    data: [107, 131, 635, 203, 29, 152, 954, 420, 740, 38, 42, 156]
}, {
    name: 'Item 2',
    data: [133, 50, 0, 408, 6, 40, 107, 31, 635, 203, 222, 225]
}, {
    name: 'Item 3',
    data: [152, 200, 420, 740, 38, 133, 156, 947, 152, 408, 6, 40]
}]
```

1. В примере, в феврале, соответствующее значения item не сортированы, а нужно сделать, как показано на картинке. Т.е. внутри месяца, значения сортировались по возрастанию.
2. В марте значение одного из item равно нулю, как сделать, чтобы как на картинке, оно даже не показывалось? Т.е. если есть нулевое значение, не выводит его?

Понимаю, что нужен метод-обработчик этого объекта, но как его правильно добавить?

[image: Пример, как должно быть]

Comment: Ну, тут никакая обработка объектов не поможет. Нужно либо использовать API скрипта чарта, если там такие возможности есть, либо копать сам движок

Answer (score 0):

Решение предложено на форуме поддержки Highcharts:

> In order to achieve desired behaviour, you can create 2D array of your data, map it that every point should contain y value and color, then rotate your array and sort each row, then rotate it back and save to original series array last step would be mapping 0 values to null.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tt3ayvrk/)

```
// Initial data
var data = [
  [107, 131, 635, 203, 29, 152, 954, 420, 740, 38, 42, 156],
  [133, 50, 0, 408, 6, 40, 107, 31, 635, 203, 222, 225],
  [152, 200, 420, 740, 38, 133, 156, 947, 152, 408, 6, 40]
];
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

// Map array of numbers to array of objects with color property
var series = data.map((serieData, index) => {
  return {
    name: 'Item ' + index,
    data: serieData.map((pointData, i) => {
        return {
        y: pointData,
        color: colors[index]
      }
    })
  }
});

// Create rotated array
var width = series[0].data.length;
var height = series.length;
var rotated = [];
for (let i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
    rotated[j] = rotated[j] ? rotated[j] : {data: []};
    rotated[j].data.push(series[height-i-1].data[width-j-1])
  }
}

// Sort every row of rotated array
for (let i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    rotated[i].data.sort((a, b) => a.y < b.y ? 1 : (a.y > b.y ? -1 : 0));
}

// Rotate back and update series array
for (let i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
    series[j] = series[j] ? series[j] : {data: []};
    series[j].data[i] = rotated[width-i-1].data[height-j-1]
  }
}

// Filter empty elements
series = series.map(seriesData => {
    seriesData.data = seriesData.data.map(pointData => !!pointData.y ? pointData : null);
  return seriesData;
});

// Options
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ]
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 80,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  series: series
};

// Create chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```